# Hello I need some Help in apex class I Want to upload attachment When i click on Attach Button it give me some error please help me

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, visualforce-component, visual-workflow

Visualforce Error

> Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size
>   for this page was 157.188KB

this is my apex class

```
public class ClaimAttachment_1 {
      public Id recId{get;set;}
      public String contIdChosen {get; set;}

public Attachment attachment {get;set;}


   public string fileName{
      get;set;}

  public Blob fileBody {
      get;set;}
public string contentType {
      get;set;}



  public ClaimAttachment_1(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    recId = controller.getRecord().Id;
      attachment = new Attachment();}


  public List<Attachment> getAttachments(){
      string AttParentId = apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
      list<attachment> att = [select Id,Name,BodyLength,CreatedDate,CreatedById,OwnerId,contentType from Attachment where parentId =:AttParentId ];
      return att;} 


  public PageReference returnPage(){
  return Page.ClaimAttachment_1;}

    public PageReference UploadFile()
{
    PageReference pr;
    if(fileBody != null && fileName != null)
    {

      attachment.Body = fileBody;
      attachment.Name = fileName;
        attachment.contentType = contentType;

      attachment.ParentId = recId;
      insert attachment;
    //  pr = new PageReference('/' + myAttachment.Id);
      //pr.setRedirect(true);
       // return pr;
      return Page.ClaimAttachment;
    }
    return null;
}       

  public PageReference delCont(){
  attachment toDel=new attachment(id=contIdChosen);
  delete todel;
  return null;}

 public PageReference Back()
{
 return Page.ClaimAttachment;
    }
}

// <apex:iframe  src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, att.Id)}" height="100%;" width="100%;"/>
//  return Page.ClaimAttachment;
//   <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, att.Id)}" target="_blank">View</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: This might give you a brief idea of what is wrong with the design[Click Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090oVIAQ) .
Try using transient variables as much as possible. Here is a referal [link] (http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2010/11/best-practise-to-write-apex.html)

Answer (score 0):

view state:- 
    -View state is a state of you VF page, which help salesforce to regenerate VF page when it come back from server
    -As its name suggests, it holds the state of the page-state that includes the components, field values and controller state.
The data in the view state should be sufficient to recreate the state of the page when the postback is received.

To do this, it stores the following data:
1.All non-transient data members in the associated controller (either standard or custom) and the controller extensions.
2.Objects that are reachable from a non-transient data member in a controller or controller extension.
3.The component tree for that page, which represents the page's component structure and the associated state, which are the   values applied to those components.
4.A small amount of data for Visualforce to do housekeeping.

You Can handle this Using transient keyword:-
Use the transient keyword to declare instance variables that can't be saved, and shouldn't be transmitted as part of the view state for a Visualforce page. 
Refer following Code:

```
  public class ClaimAttachment_1 {
     transient public Id recId{get;set;}
     transient public String contIdChosen {get; set;}

     transient public Attachment attachment {get;set;}


   transient public string fileName{
      get;set;}

  transient public Blob fileBody {
      get;set;}
transient public string contentType {
      get;set;}



  public ClaimAttachment_1(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    recId = controller.getRecord().Id;
      attachment = new Attachment();}


  public List<Attachment> getAttachments(){
      string AttParentId = apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
      list<attachment> att = [select Id,Name,BodyLength,CreatedDate,CreatedById,OwnerId,contentType from Attachment where parentId =:AttParentId ];
      return att;} 


  public PageReference returnPage(){
  return Page.ClaimAttachment_1;}

    public PageReference UploadFile()
{
    PageReference pr;
    if(fileBody != null && fileName != null)
    {

      attachment.Body = fileBody;
      attachment.Name = fileName;
        attachment.contentType = contentType;

      attachment.ParentId = recId;
      insert attachment;
    //  pr = new PageReference('/' + myAttachment.Id);
      //pr.setRedirect(true);
       // return pr;
      return Page.ClaimAttachment;
    }
    return null;
}       

  public PageReference delCont(){
  attachment toDel=new attachment(id=contIdChosen);
  delete todel;
  return null;}

 public PageReference Back()
{
 return Page.ClaimAttachment;
    }
}
```

please mark this as a best answer if this is helpful
thanx

Comment: I made some change on apex class but still it give me error

Comment: Maximum view state size limit (135KB) exceeded. Actual view state size for this page was 157.079KB

Answer (score 0):

> Visual-force imposes a limit of 135K on your view state - if the view size exceeds this limit, an exception gets thrown.

It is about what all areas are to be covered while writing Apex code.

- Firstly only those variables which are used on visual force page should be **public** rest all variables should be **private**, if not used by any other class.
- Secondly the most important thing which we generally ignore while working with visual force wizard is to make variables **TRANSIENT** which leads to increase the view state size. Use of **Transient** keyword to declare instance variable that can not be saved, and shouldn't be transmitted as part of the view state for visual force page.
- Thirdly, we should take care of the **Heap Size(3 MB)** while writing apex. We should nullify all the instance of objects which are no longer in use

**Change Your above code**

Declare variable **Attachments** as **transient**

```
   public transient List<Attachment> Attachments;
```

Edited below function so that your returning list of attachment and it will not save in view State.

```
    public List<Attachment> getAttachments(){
          string AttParentId = apexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
          Attachments= new list<attachment>(); 
          Attachments = [select Id,Name,BodyLength,CreatedDate,CreatedById,OwnerId,contentType from Attachment where parentId =:AttParentId ];
          return Attachments;
     }
```

Follow the above Steps and reduce the view state size.
[More About Transient](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_transient.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful while uploading file from visualforce page. Because the size of the file count against view state. Also you have to take care of variables to be declare as transient. Write javascript code to limit the file size (don't allow to upload large file)

Answer (score 0):

When you are getting this error. On the page load of while performing some action ?

Basically this error occurs when you have stored heavy data in the variables, you need to make sure where & when you need the data.

Set variable to null or empty when not needed and try to use transient variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use transient variables as mentioned in Answers. If it still doesn't resolve your issue, you reset the attachments after processing is done. Means at the end of your method/class use something like this,

```
this.attachment = new Attachment();
```

Having said that I will be using wrappers on all attachment related processing